# React App protected routes throw Access denied error - hosted on AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have hosted my react app on AWS Amplify. On trying to access a protected route of the application I am getting the following error on screen This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>3C8377104116CA48</RequestId>
<HostId>nL3bDs+kXEWE8uBFPTLkFLpRg6CCmKfejftWs5wmTWYO6K6WDzpwsDXJCFTK0EFhjJdaHECfuos=</HostId>
</Error>
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Route redirects and rewrites has special configuration for a deployed AWS Amplify app. Check the

> AWS Amplify Console > App Settings > Rewrites and Redirects

Configuring a rewrite rule fixed this issue for me.
My rule looks like so:
Source -

```
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|yaml|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff2|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>
```

Target -

```
/index.html
```

Type -

```
200 (Rewrite)
```

Detailed description is here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html